# OpenCL ptxas error

Tags: opencv, opengl, opencl

I'm launching a program of mine which uses openCV/Opengl and which used to work fine with no errors. Now when it starts I get this:

```
OpenCL program build log: -D LOCAL_SIZE_X=8 -D LOCAL_SIZE_Y=8 -D SPLIT_STAGE=1 -D N_STAGES=20 -D MAX_FACES=10000 -D LBP
ptxas application ptx input, line 637; error   : Instruction '{atom,red}.shared' requires .target sm_12 or higher
ptxas application ptx input, line 884; error   : Instruction '{atom,red}.shared' requires .target sm_12 or higher
ptxas fatal   : Ptx assembly aborted due to errors
```

(Mac Os X 10.11)

and then my program continues running normally. I have no idea what might be causing this and if this is relevant or not to my code and I have no idea where to look either. The very same code used to be OK. Is it something related to the openGL wrapper libraries I use? How serious is this? Could somebody please explain this error to me?

**EDIT**

I managed to identify the code which causes this error:

```
  face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0, cv::Size(80, 80));
```

this is essentially a call to `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale` with a `cv::Mat` a `std::vector<cv::Rect>` an a `cv::Size` as arguments.

Comment: Double check that the NVidia drivers are properly installed; maybe they got corrupted during a system update (ptxas is part of the NVidia GPU toolchain)

Comment: any idea of how to do this on a macbook?? Note that this is the on-board nvidia graphics card, I never installed any drivers myself.

Comment: I suggest installing the latest CUDA drivers (which includes the GPU and OpenCL drivers): http://www.nvidia.com/object/macosx-cuda-7.5.25-driver.html

Comment: @datenwolf done, but the problem remains..

Comment: If it used to work and then stopped, what happened in between?

Comment: as far as I remember I just updated glfw to the latest revision from github, could this be related?

Comment: I managed to identify the code that causes this to happen, added an edit in my original question.